# Identifying different versions in the registry using WIX 3.5

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6, wixlib

I have a requirement like:
The earlier versions of the product leaves back some registry entries which needs to be cleaned up using WIX 3.5 in Visual

Approach:
Search the installed versions of the product from the registry
Then, search each registry entry which doesnot match with the version of the product version and do Registry Action=remove.

How can I achieve this?
How can I store all the versions of a product while doing a RegistrySearch in WIX?

Can anyone please provide the code of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the registry keys are unique to your product and need removed when installing the latest version of the product, then there isn't really a need to check for various previous versions. Simply just remove the registry keys during install, regardless of what was previously installed. If the keys already exist they will be deleted, if not, then no worries.

Comment: I have a doubt: What happens when we uninstall a software (created by install shield or WIX). Does it remove the registry values created in HKCR and HKLM?. If we are registering COM dlls and .net Dlls using install shield or WIX, what happens to the registry entries when we uninstall COM dlls?

Comment: Generally speaking, if the installer writes the reg keys it will remove them on uninstall, at least depending on how the installer was authored. In reference to registering COM dlls it depends on how they are registered. InstallShield and Wix both allow you to mark the dlls as self registered (NOT RECOMMENDED) and this could potentially lead to scenarios where the registry entries aren't removed on uninstall. InstallShield and WiX both have tools to analyze dlls and get the Com information to write to the registry. The WiX tool is called Heat.

Comment: ...forgot to mention. The output generated by Heat will allow you to remove those COM registry entries on uninstall.